# Como gravar o caminho da pasta no banco de dados?

Tags: java-ee, jsf-2.2, upload

Saudação para todos,

Criei uma aplicação que está salvando os registro no banco de dados, como mostra na figura;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa aplicação está tendo sucesso em salvar o titulo, data e descrição,  e está conseguindo fazer o upload da imagem para a pasta que determinada, porém eu quero salvar o caminho da pasta no banco de dados, como faço para fazer isso?

Aqui está a entidade Noticia;

```
package br.com.vendelancha.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

@Entity
public class Noticia implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;
    private String titulo_noticia;
    private Date data_noticia;
    private String foto_noticia;
    private String desc_noticia;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 80)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getTitulo_noticia() {
        return titulo_noticia;
    }

    public void setTitulo_noticia(String titulo_noticia) {
        this.titulo_noticia = titulo_noticia;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    public Date getData_noticia() {
        return data_noticia;
    }

    public void setData_noticia(Date data_noticia) {
        this.data_noticia = data_noticia;
    }

    public String getFoto_noticia() {
        return foto_noticia;
    }

    public void setFoto_noticia(String foto_noticia) {
        this.foto_noticia = foto_noticia;
    }

    @NotBlank
    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    public String getDesc_noticia() {
        return desc_noticia;
    }

    public void setDesc_noticia(String desc_noticia) {
        this.desc_noticia = desc_noticia;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Noticia other = (Noticia) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Aqui está a pagina XHTML;

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/LayoutSystem.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">



    <!-- xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" -->

    <ui:define name="titulo">Novas Notícias</ui:define>

    <ui:define name="corpo">

        <h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h1>Novas Notícias</h1>

            <p:messages autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />

            <p:toolbar style="margin-top: 20px">
                <p:toolbarGroup>
                    <p:button value="Novo" />


                    <h:commandButton value="Salvar" id="botaoSalvar"
                        action="#{cadastroNoticiaBean.salvar}">
                        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@all"/>
                    </h:commandButton>

                </p:toolbarGroup>


                <p:toolbarGroup align="right">
                    <p:button value="Pesquisa"
                        outcome="/noticias/PesquisaNoticias.xhtml" />
                </p:toolbarGroup>
            </p:toolbar>

            <div id="wrap">

                <div class="left-sidebar">
                    <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="painel1"
                        style="width: 50%; margin-top: 20px" columnClasses="rotulo, campo">


                        <p:outputLabel value="Titulo" for="titulo" />
                        <p:inputText id="titulo" size="20" maxlength="50"
                            value="#{cadastroNoticiaBean.noticia.titulo_noticia}" />

                        <p:outputLabel value="Data" for="data_noticia" />
                        <p:calendar id="data_noticia" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
                            value="#{cadastroNoticiaBean.noticia.data_noticia}" />



                        <p:outputLabel value="Descrição" for="descricao" />

                        <p:inputText id="descricao" size="20" maxlength="250"
                            value="#{cadastroNoticiaBean.noticia.desc_noticia}" />



                        <p:outputLabel value="Foto" />
                        <h:inputFile value="#{cadastroNoticiaBean.arquivo}" />




                    </p:panelGrid>
                </div>
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Aqui está minha classe Bean;

```
package br.com.vendelancha.controller;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

import br.com.vendelancha.model.Noticia;
import br.com.vendelancha.service.CadastroNoticiaService;
import br.com.vendelancha.util.jsf.FacesUtil;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CadastroNoticiaBean implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Noticia noticia;
    private Part arquivo;
    private String nomeArquivoSaida;

    @Inject
    private CadastroNoticiaService cadastroNoticiaService;

    public CadastroNoticiaBean() {
        limpar();
    }

    public void limpar(){
        noticia = new Noticia();

    }

    public void salvar() {
        this.noticia = cadastroNoticiaService.salvar(this.noticia);
        upload();
        limpar();
        FacesUtil.addInfoMessage("Noticia salva com sucesso! ");
    }


    public void upload() {


         nomeArquivoSaida = "C:/workspace Web/Projetos Profissionais/Fotos para teste/" + arquivo.getSubmittedFileName();


        try (InputStream is = arquivo.getInputStream();
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(nomeArquivoSaida)) {

            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            FacesUtil.addErrorMessage("Erro ao enviar arquivo.");
        }
    }





    public Noticia getNoticia() {
        return noticia;
    }

    public Part getArquivo() {
        return arquivo;
    }

    public void setArquivo(Part arquivo) {
        this.arquivo = arquivo;
    }

    public String getNomeArquivoSaida() {
        return nomeArquivoSaida;
    }

    public void setNomeArquivoSaida(String nomeArquivoSaida) {
        this.nomeArquivoSaida = nomeArquivoSaida;
    }

}
```

Comment: De acordo com seu caso eu suponho que você precisará acessar essas fotos na sua aplicação, correto? Então tenho uma dúvida: você está salvando as imagens dentro de uma pasta na sua aplicação?

Comment: Ainda não estou salvando a pasta dentro da minha aplicação, mas isso não é problema e só mudar o caminho, o caminho está descrito na postagem. Vou precisar sim, acessar essas fotos.